# Issue with making a struct equal to a value from different class and return that value by an instance

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, struct, operator-keyword

Let say I have struct 'A' of type MyStruct with a variable 'i' of type int in this struct. I want to make a statement

```
MyStruct A = i;
```

and then A will store the value of 'i' in it. Then when I call

```
print(a);
```

I want it to return the value of 'i' in itself. The reason I want to do this is because I want to keep my code as clean as possible by not using constructor. How can I do this in C#?

PS. For the first question, I tried to define the operator = as following

```
public static MyStruct operator =(MyStruct s,int i){

}
```

But it have a syntax error. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What do you mean by "I want it to return the value of 'i' in itself"? My advice to you is to write normal code and not worry about making up strange rules for yourself like not using constructors. Once you've gained a basic familiarity with the language, then you can invent new and better ways to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
     private readonly int myValue;

     public MyStruct(int value) { myValue = value; }
     public override string ToString => myValue.ToString();
     public static implicit operator MyStruct(int i) => new MyStruct(i);
}
```

And now you can do:

```
MyStruct myStruct = 1; //will impicitly cast int to MyStruct
Console.WriteLine(myStruct); //will print 1
```

I've omitted, becuase its not germane to the question at hand, implementing `IEquatable<MyStruct>` and overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals` but you should most definitely do so; you can find tons of questions asking how to do so properly.

Now, the question is: why would you need a thin wrapper over an existing type in the framework? What are you trying to do?

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. To answer your question, I want a wrapper because I'm working in a huge project which have 'A' (and so many of this variables in my project) as an int. Then, after I decided to 'do some calculation' with 'A's before it output its value, my project is so huge that it would take a long time to implement constructors (and possible bugs) to every variables in the projects.

Comment: If possible, could you demonstrate how to use IEquatable to solve this question. This is not directly relate to my question but I just want to know. I've read the example code in the docs and have no idea how to implement IEquatable to this case.

Comment: @Maou Are you saying that you're doing this crazy stuff because you changed an int to a struct throughout your project, and you want to avoid some typing by treating the struct type as if it were still int? That is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the following link, the operator `=` cannot be overloaded:
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators)

What I assume you want is, to set the value defined in the field named `i` of the struct `MyStruct`, which you can do with the `.` operator. For example:

```
Int anIntValue = 1;
MyStruct A.i = anIntValue;
```

What I suspect with that "print" thing, that you want to achive a print to an output ( console or something else). To do so use the `System.Console.WriteLine(A.i)` or write your own print method like:

```
public static void print(MyStruct B){
    System.Console.WriteLine(B.i)
}
```

Invoke like this:

```
MyStruct.print(A);
```

Please look up c# property. From the given information, i shall assume that it would clarify your understanding in your problem.
Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I choose to not using A.i because I have so many variable in the project I'm working and I think it would be easier to implement it this way than edit every variables in my projects to be A.i